# Ng-bind - Can't replace the text immediately

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I try to change the text with `ng-bind`and read this text. But I can't do it - text is empty. How can I do it? Thank you

```
    function Controller($scope) {
       $scope.sometext = 'yo'; 
       someFun();

       function someFun() {
         alert($('.yo').text());
       }
    }
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/XMTQC/27/)

Comment: It needs digest cycle to run update DOM... also alert is a blocking activity..  and virtually 2 scripts cannot run at the same time...

Comment: @PSL, but I run the function after updating $scope. How can I fix it?

Comment: It does not update as soon as you change the value of the modal. Try putting it in a `$timeout` it should ensure that the timeout is run after the digest cycle is dnoe

Comment: @PSL, `timeout` is dirty, i think. Thank you! Now I understand why. I'll try to make new way.

Comment: Yes that is what you need to read upon "dirty" checking and angular digst cycle.. :) I was not suggesting you to use `$timeout` told that so that you can see why...

Comment: when do you want the alert box to show up?